# How do I merge two sorted files into one sorted file?

Tags: c, file, merge

Being more specific, I want to merge two sorted lists of integers into a third list that is also sorted. I can't figure out why my code isn't working! Here's some example of entries and the code I made:

File1:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

File2:

```
7
8
9
9
9
10
```

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void merge(char* arq1, char* arq2){
    FILE* final;
    final = fopen("merge.txt",'w');
    FILE* f1 = fopen(arq1,'rt');
    FILE* f2 = fopen(arq2,'rt');
    if(!f1 || !f2) exit(1);
    // n1 and n2 represents the actual value that's been read. r1 and r2 the status of each file.
    int n1,n2,r1,r2,equal;
    r1 = fscanf(f1,"%d",&n1);
    r2 = fscanf(f2,"%d",&n2);
    while(r1 || r2){
         if((!r1) || (n2 < n1)){
            fprintf(final,"%d ",n2);
            r2 = fscanf(f2,"%d",&n2);
        }else if((!r2) || (n1 < n2)){
            fprintf(final,"%d ",n1);
            r1 = fscanf(f1,"%d",&n1);
        }else{
            equal = n1;
            fprintf(final,"%d ",equal);
            while(n1 == equal) r1 = fscanf(f1,"%d",&n1);
            while(n2 == equal) r2 = fscanf(f2,"%d",&n2);
        }
    }
    fclose(final);
    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    merge("merge1.txt","merge2.txt"); 

    return 0;
}
```

The algorithm is supposed to work as follows:

While at least one of the files still has content, its content would be then saved at the `merge.txt` file. If file 1 and 2 would possess the same content, I'd save the content and make the 2 files read until they find a different value so that the merged file does not have repeated values.

How do I merge two sorted files into one sorted file?

Comment: How exactly is it not working? What's the output as is?

Comment: Listen to your compiler warnings; the strings for the mode argument of `fopen` need to be delimited by `"`.

Comment: Also: `fscanf()` can return EOF.

Comment: Note that your merging code only eliminates duplicates if the same number appears in both files.  If one of the files contains duplicates that the other doesn’t, those duplicates are preserved.  Also, your sample data is not a good test data set.  You need sample data with overlapping ranges in the two files, rather than all of file A preceding all of file B.

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much, I completely forgot about double versus single quotation marks. as regarding the tests, the exercise is supposed to be a simple one, altough I really didn't think about this situation could happen. I'll gladly correct my code now.

Comment: This question would be much clearer if you illustrated it with what you expect the output file to contain and what it actually contains.  Your remark about duplicates is entirely unclear given that there are no duplicates between the files (only within the second file set).  You would do better to choose test data that demonstrated _all_ the required behaviour; data that actually required "merging" rather that simply concatenation would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. the mode-argument for `fopen()` should be a string.
2. `fscanf()` can return EOF(-1) on error or EOF
3. On failure, the value of the target variable(s) for `fscanf()` is undefined.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void merge(char* arq1, char* arq2){
    FILE *final;
    final = fopen("merge.txt", "w"); // <<--(1)
    FILE *f1 = fopen(arq1, "rt"); // <<--(1)
    FILE *f2 = fopen(arq2, "rt"); // <<--(1)
    if(!f1 || !f2 || !final) exit(1); // <<--(1)
    // n1 and n2 represents the actual value that's been read. r1 and r2 the status of each file.
    int n1,n2,r1,r2,equal;

    r1 = fscanf(f1, "%d", &n1);
    r2 = fscanf(f2, "%d", &n2);
    while(r1>0 || r2>0){ // <<--(2)
         if(r1 < 1 || n2 < n1){ // <<--(2)
            fprintf(final, "%d ", n2);
            r2 = fscanf(f2, "%d", &n2);
        }else if(r2 < 1 || n1 < n2){ // <<--(2)
            fprintf(final, "%d ", n1);
            r1 = fscanf(f1, "%d", &n1);
        }else{
            equal = n1;
            fprintf(final, "%d ", equal);
            while(n1 == equal && r1 > 0) r1 = fscanf(f1, "%d", &n1); // <<--(2,3)
            while(n2 == equal && r2 > 0) r2 = fscanf(f2, "%d", &n2); // <<--(2,3)
        }
    }
    fclose(final);
    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    merge("merge1.txt","merge2.txt"); 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

the OPs posted code fails to cleanly compile!

Here is the output from the compiler:

```
gcc    -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11  -c "untitled.c"  

untitled.c: In function ‘merge’:
untitled.c:6:31: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘fopen’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     final = fopen("merge.txt",'w');
                               ^~~

In file included from untitled.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:232:14: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 extern FILE *fopen (const char *__restrict __filename,
              ^~~~~

untitled.c:7:27: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
     FILE* f1 = fopen(arq1,'rt');
                           ^~~~

untitled.c:7:27: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘fopen’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

In file included from untitled.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:232:14: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 extern FILE *fopen (const char *__restrict __filename,
              ^~~~~

untitled.c:8:27: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
     FILE* f2 = fopen(arq2,'rt');
                           ^~~~

untitled.c:8:27: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘fopen’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

In file included from untitled.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:232:14: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 extern FILE *fopen (const char *__restrict __filename,
              ^~~~~

untitled.c: In function ‘main’:
untitled.c:33:14: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
              ^~~~

untitled.c:33:32: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
                                ^~~~
```

regarding:

```
final = fopen("merge.txt",'w');
```

the 'mode' parameter must be a string.  Suggest using double quotes around the 'mode' parameter:

```
final = fopen("merge.txt","w");
```

regarding:

```
FILE* f1 = fopen(arq1,'rt');
```

as before, the 'mode' parameter must be a string.  Suggest:

```
FILE* f1 = fopen(arq1,"rt");
```

for the `main()` function, since the parameters are not being used, suggest using the signature:

```
int main( void )
```

When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings

Comment: the OPs code is not working due to the compile problems so why the down vote?